# How can get data between two defined characters in a string? r

Tags: r, filtering

I've seen this problem answered here in other languages, but can't find the solution in r:

I have a dataset where order of interactions is crucial, and depending on how the experiment has progressed, the apparatus can have one of two states. The hardware doesn't note the current state though, so the only way to separate the states is to filter the data between 'start' and 'stop' interactions. State 1 is outside of the 'start'-'stop' and state 2 is everything between a 'start' and a 'stop'.

My data is in the following format:

```
Time       Individual    Interaction
11:57:31   XX002         2
12:00:00   XX123         Start
12:00:03   XX123         1
12:00:37   XX334         2
12:01:00   NA            Stop
12:04:12   XX441         2
```

How can I filter the data to get two separate dfs, one for all occurrences outside of 'start'-'stop', and another for everything between 'start' and 'stop'? Ideally it would result in the data being searched chronologically for a 'start' interaction, then filtering out all the data between that and the next 'stop', and repeat (as there can sometimes be multiple 'start' interactions before the next stop.

In this example it would result in:

```
Time       Individual    Interaction
11:57:31   XX002         2
12:04:12   XX441         2
```

and

```
Time       Individual    Interaction
12:00:00   XX123         Start
12:00:03   XX123         1
12:00:37   XX334         2
12:01:00   NA            Stop
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` we accumulate the changes in `Start` and `Stop`. Substracting both we get `1` when in between `start/stop` and `0` when out. Sadly, we need to use `lag()` to put the value in `stop` also in the `dfin` as it also has a 0.

```
z = cumsum(df$Interaction=="Start")-cumsum(df$Interaction=="Stop")
sep = ifelse(z==0 & lag(z,default=z[1])==1,1,z)
dfoin=df[sep==1,]
dfout=df[sep==0,]

> dfout
      Time Individual Interaction
3 12:00:00      XX123       Start
4 12:00:03      XX123           1
5 12:00:37      XX334           2
6 12:01:00       <NA>        Stop
> dfin
      Time Individual Interaction
2 11:57:31      XX002           2
7 12:04:12      XX441           2
```

Using `dplyr`piping

```
df2=df%>%mutate(n=cumsum(Interaction=="Start")-cumsum(Interaction=="Stop"))%>%
  mutate(n=ifelse(n==0 & lag(z,default=z[1])==1,1,z))%>%split(.$n) 
> df2
$`0`
      Time Individual Interaction n
1 11:57:31      XX002           2 0
6 12:04:12      XX441           2 0

$`1`
      Time Individual Interaction n
2 12:00:00      XX123       Start 1
3 12:00:03      XX123           1 1
4 12:00:37      XX334           2 1
5 12:01:00       <NA>        Stop 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try finding the times of the start and stop interactions, and then subset the data frame based on that:

```
time_start <- df$Time[df$Interaction == "Start"]
time_stop  <- df$Time[df$Interaction == "Stop"]

df_in <- df[df$Time >= time_start & df$Time <= time_stop,]
df_out <- df[df$Time < time_start | df$Time > time_stop,]

df_in
      Time Individual Interaction
2 12:00:00      XX123       Start
3 12:00:03      XX123           1
4 12:00:37      XX334           2
5 12:01:00       <NA>        Stop

df_out
      Time Individual Interaction
1 11:57:31      XX002           2
6 12:04:12      XX441           2
```